# flutter 3.3 ShaderCompilerException ink_sparkle.frag failed with exit code -1073740791

Tags: windows, flutter, shader, flutter-web

Since updating my flutter to 3.3+ everytime I try to build my project there is this error on the console:

```
Target web_release_bundle failed: ShaderCompilerException: Shader compilation of
"C:\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\material\shaders\ink_sparkle.frag" to "build\web\assets\shaders/ink_sparkle.frag"
failed with exit code -1073740791.

Compiling lib\main.dart for the Web...                             52,1s
Exception: Failed to compile application for the Web.
```

I've tried running flutter clean, deleting the project and downloading it again from github, clearing pub-cache from c:\flutter folder and also deleting flutter and installing it again but nothing worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is present since 3.3.0 and until today (3.3.2), it wasn't fixed... but there are some workarounds:

1- Downgrade flutter to 3.0.5 (some updates to the libs you use won't be avaliable as they are migrating to 3.3+)

2- They are currently tracking the issue on [github](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/107590#issuecomment-1247534623) and the 'temp fix' is checking if your project is in a folder with a utf8 character (like 'â', 'Á' and maybe some chinese or japanese characters) and moving it to a folder only with ASCII characters.

Ex:

```
from -> C:\Users\user\Área de Trabalho\
to -> C:\Users\user\
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using a mac try to open 'Security & Privacy' and give permission to the app that requests it. [image: Image Example]

It may seem out of context. But it worked for me!

**22/02/2023 UPDATE**

The solution also works for this type of error:
Error (Xcode): Target release_ios_bundle_flutter_assets failed: IconTreeShakerException: Font subsetting failed with exit code -9.

Answer (score 0):

I tried a few versions and it wasn't working, so I went back to version 3.0.1 and it finally worked. Now it's wait and see if it fixes the problem for newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

if you get this error
Error (Xcode): Target debug_ios_bundle_flutter_assets failed: ShaderCompilerException:
so just open "Xcode workspace" run your application through Xcode wait for some seconds after launching cancel everything then open your application folder in VS code then run your application it worked for me